# Using a shell that has a hash as the primary prompt in Python Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have a need where the shell I'm using has the PS1 variable set to `#` instead of `$`.  I tried using `env.prompts`, but that's a bit heavyweight having to script each possible step to respond in kind to a hash symbol.  shell_env applies to adding environment variables to the remote session once it's established, so I ran into a dead end there.

Is anyone aware of how to change the default prompt from `$` to `#` when using fabric?

Comment: `#` indicates effective uid is 0, aka root. why you want to change prompt in fab, i guess what you really want is to change current user?

Comment: The shell in question is in an environment where there are no other users.  This is why they shell prompt is '# '.  So, no.  I don't want to su or use sudo.

Comment: interesting, then what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not able to use the shell interactively as a result of a different prompt.  So, being able to use the run() method.  That's what I'm trying to achieve.  Just using the API despite the unexpected PS1 prompt.

Comment: bash prompt shall not interfere with `run`, why not provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be that this isn't supported in [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1658).  I've solved my problem using pexpect's pxssh.  In the login method, it's possible to specify an alternative original_prompt that persists for the duration of the connection when auto_prompt_reset is set to False.  Thus, something like:

```
from pexpect.pxssh import pxssh

# Set the ssh options for the connection.
conn = pxssh(options={'IdentityFile' : '/path/to/id_pem', 'StrictHostKeyChecking' : 'no', 'UserKnownHostsFile' : '/dev/null'})
conn.login(username='user', server='192.168.30.1', original_prompt='# ', auto_prompt_reset=False)
```

That does the trick for me.  The original prompt might not be comprehensive for some people's usage, but it works for me in this case on this SOC with a limited shell.  The same could be done for any number of other non-standard interactive shells like routers, network connected PDUs, etc.

The only downside is that it's not fabric.